# Javascript detect language and redirect

Tags: javascript

I know there are many answers here. I have tried the following codes, but it keep not workings or keep redirect with showing a blank page.
I just want to detect all using Chinese language to go to the page with chinese, others go to English page.

How should I sueccessful do this function in a simple way?

Should i placed the detect code in both chi and eng page? and if the url included the "utm", how to keep this url with url after redirect?

http://www.testing.com/tc/testing.html?utm_source=test

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
switch(userLang){
    case 'zh-CN':
        window.location.href = '/tc/testing.html;
        break;
    case 'zh-TW':
        window.location.href = '/tc/testing.html';
        break;
    case 'zh-HK':
        window.location.href = '/tc/testing.html';
        break;
    default:
        // if it's something else fall back to the default
        window.location.href = '/tc/testing.html';
        break;
}
    </script>
```

Or

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var language = window.navigator.language;
if(language == 'zh-CN' || language == 'zh-TW' || language == 'zh-HK')
{
window.location.href = '../tc/testing.html'
}

else {
window.location.href = '../en/testing.html'
}

</script>
```

Comment: could you add the structure of the folder where you are working. It may be something missing. always try to debug from the conosle of chrome or your web browser

Comment: Your code should work. The path is probably wrong. When it load, what does the URL look like?